# Vector elements inserted into a linked list?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list, token, tokenize

I'm trying to create a function which take in a Vector of Tokens, which is a type defined by my professor, and enter each element of the vector into the linked list, I return the head of the first element. The cout statement in the last part of new_list shows that I am indeed inserting the elements of the vector into the linked list. So when I type in:

new a 9 2 3

9 2 3 are being inserted

The print_list_cmd is defined by my professor and is supposed out the list that I created by calling new a, 
so, 
print a should return 
9 2 3 
but when I type print I only get the last element of the linked list which is 3.

I have two questions my code is not very elegant is there a better way to insert a vector of tokens into a linked list? Two why is the print command only returning the last element in the linked list? Also there is a lexer class that tokenizes the input but it's alot of code so I didn't insert it, if it's helpful or you need me to insert it I will.

```
struct Node {
int   key;
Node* next;
Node(int k=0, Node* n=NULL) : key(k), next(n) {};
};


Node* new_list(const vector<Token>& tok_vec){

//int key;
Node *head;
Node *newHead;
Node *headPointer = NULL;

newHead = new Node;
newHead -> next = NULL;
head = NULL;

for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < tok_vec.size() ; i++){

   // newHead -> key = tok_vec.at(i).value;
      string myStream = tok_vec.at(i).value;
      istringstream buffer(myStream);
      int value;
      buffer >> value;
      newHead -> key = value;

    if(!head){

        head = newHead;

        }else{

            headPointer = newHead;

            while(headPointer -> next){

                headPointer = headPointer -> next;
                headPointer -> next = newHead;

                }
           }
 cout << head->key << endl;
}

return head->key;

}

void print_list_cmd(Lexer lex){
Token tok = lex.next_token();
if (tok.type != IDENT || lex.has_more_token())
    throw runtime_error("SYNTAX: print listname");
if (list_table.find(tok.value) == list_table.end())
    throw runtime_error(tok.value + " not defined or already destroyed");
print_list(list_table[tok.value]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you don't return the head of the list, you return the value from the head Node:

```
return head->key;
```

instead of:

```
return head;
```

Also, most effective way to insert new items into the list would be inserting them at the head:

```
/// inserts node at the head of the list and returns the new head;
Node* insertNode(int key, Node* head) {

Node* newHead = new Node;
newHead->key = key;
newHead->next = head;
return newHead;
}
```

you could use that as:

```
Node* new_list(const vector<Token>& tok_vec){
Node* head = NULL;

for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < tok_vec.size() ; i++){

      string myStream = tok_vec.at(i).value;
      istringstream buffer(myStream);
      int value;
      buffer >> value;
      head = insertNode(value, head);
///
}

return head;

}
```

UPDATE. the resulting list will be backwards with regard to the input, so you would have to reverse it. One of the possibilities would be to create another list from the original one, so that at the end the last element of the old list will be the head of the new one:

```
Node* reverse(Node* list) {
Node* reversed = NULL;
while (list!=NULL) {
  Node* nextNode = list;
  list = list->next;
  nextNode->next = reversed;
  reversed = nextNode;
}
return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Only problem is I am printing out the vector backwards and I am not completely sure how to fix it?

Comment: ah, you have to reverse the list. One option would be to create another list and begin to insert into it all elements from your old list, starting from the head and removing them from the old list.